# Get time as 24 hour format from RTC

Tags: esp32, rtc

I have a DS3231 RTC module.

I would like to get the time from the RTC as 24 hour format not 12 hour. The library that I'm using requires that I pass in 2 Boolean values into `Clock.getHour()`, however changing these values does not change the returned time format.

Code;

```
/*
DS3231_test.pde
Eric Ayars
4/11

Test/demo of read routines for a DS3231 RTC.

Turn on the serial monitor after loading this to check if things are
working as they should.

*/

#include <DS3231.h>
#include <Wire.h>

DS3231 clock;
bool century = false;
bool h12Flag;
bool pmFlag;
byte alarmDay, alarmHour, alarmMinute, alarmSecond, alarmBits;
bool alarmDy, alarmH12Flag, alarmPmFlag;

void setup() {
    // Start the I2C interface
    Wire.begin();
 
    // Start the serial interface
    Serial.begin(57600);
}

void loop() {
    // send what's going on to the serial monitor.
    
    // Start with the year
    Serial.print("2");
    if (century) {          // Won't need this for 89 years.
        Serial.print("1");
    } else {
        Serial.print("0");
    }
    Serial.print(clock.getYear(), DEC);
    Serial.print(' ');
    
    // then the month
    Serial.print(clock.getMonth(century), DEC);
    Serial.print(" ");
  
    // then the date
    Serial.print(clock.getDate(), DEC);
    Serial.print(" ");
  
    // and the day of the week
    Serial.print(clock.getDoW(), DEC);
    Serial.print(" ");
  
    // Finally the hour, minute, and second
    Serial.print(clock.getHour(h12Flag, pmFlag), DEC);
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.print(clock.getMinute(), DEC);
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.print(clock.getSecond(), DEC);
 
    // Add AM/PM indicator
    if (h12Flag) {
        if (pmFlag) {
            Serial.print(" PM ");
        } else {
            Serial.print(" AM ");
        }
    } else {
        Serial.print(" 24h ");
    }
 
    // Display the temperature
    Serial.print("T=");
    Serial.print(clock.getTemperature(), 2);
  
    // Tell whether the time is (likely to be) valid
    if (clock.oscillatorCheck()) {
        Serial.print(" O+");
    } else {
        Serial.print(" O-");
    }
 
    // Indicate whether an alarm went off
    if (clock.checkIfAlarm(1)) {
        Serial.print(" A1!");
    }
 
    if (clock.checkIfAlarm(2)) {
        Serial.print(" A2!");
    }
 
    // New line on display
    Serial.println();
    
    // Display Alarm 1 information
    Serial.print("Alarm 1: ");
    clock.getA1Time(alarmDay, alarmHour, alarmMinute, alarmSecond, alarmBits, alarmDy, alarmH12Flag, alarmPmFlag);
    Serial.print(alarmDay, DEC);
    if (alarmDy) {
        Serial.print(" DoW");
    } else {
        Serial.print(" Date");
    }
    Serial.print(' ');
    Serial.print(alarmHour, DEC);
    Serial.print(' ');
    Serial.print(alarmMinute, DEC);
    Serial.print(' ');
    Serial.print(alarmSecond, DEC);
    Serial.print(' ');
    if (alarmH12Flag) {
        if (alarmPmFlag) {
            Serial.print("pm ");
        } else {
            Serial.print("am ");
        }
    }
    if (clock.checkAlarmEnabled(1)) {
        Serial.print("enabled");
    }
    Serial.println();
 
    // Display Alarm 2 information
    Serial.print("Alarm 2: ");
    clock.getA2Time(alarmDay, alarmHour, alarmMinute, alarmBits, alarmDy, alarmH12Flag, alarmPmFlag);
    Serial.print(alarmDay, DEC);
    if (alarmDy) {
        Serial.print(" DoW");
    } else {
        Serial.print(" Date");
    }
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.print(alarmHour, DEC);
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.print(alarmMinute, DEC);
    Serial.print(" ");
    if (alarmH12Flag) {
        if (alarmPmFlag) {
            Serial.print("pm");
        } else {
            Serial.print("am");
        }
    }
    if (clock.checkAlarmEnabled(2)) {
        Serial.print("enabled");
    }
 
    // display alarm bits
  Serial.println();
    Serial.print("Alarm bits: ");
    Serial.println(alarmBits, BIN);

    Serial.println();
    delay(1000);
}
```

How do I make this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The library that I'm using requires that I pass in 2 Boolean values
> into Clock.getHour(), however changing these values does not change
> the returned time format.

You appear to be talking about the parameters [here](https://github.com/NorthernWidget/DS3231/blob/v1.0.7/DS3231.h#L73), which the second is for getting the current state of the AM/PM flag and configuration and not altering the kind of value you get in the return.

There's a [setClockMode function](https://github.com/NorthernWidget/DS3231/blob/v1.0.7/DS3231.h#L102/DS3231.h#L106) you can call which will configure the chip to report in 24-hour mode.  If you call that passing in `false`, `getHour` should begin returning 24-hour time.